# Script Activity in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Script Activity with the following sql script in my data pipeline as follows:

```
@concat('ALTER TABLE tbl',replace(pipeline().RunId,'-',''),' ADD Depth int; WITH emp AS ( SELECT *, 1 AS d FROM tbl',replace(pipeline().RunId,'-',''),' WHERE Email = ','EMAIL',' UNION ALL SELECT e.*, emp.d + 1 FROM tbl',replace(pipeline().RunId,'-',''),' e INNER JOIN emp ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber), ForUpd as (SELECT PersonnelNumber, d FROM emp) UPDATE tbl',replace(pipeline().RunId,'-',''),' SET Depth = B.d FROM tbl',replace(pipeline().RunId,'-',''),' A JOIN ForUpd B ON A.PersonnelNumber = B.PersonnelNumber')
```

I see this error on running pipeline:

> Operation on target Add Depth Column failed: Invalid column name 'EMAIL'.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are right! table name is tbl<pipeline run id>. but I think I got it working let me update my question with where I'm having issue now, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Converting the dynamic content that you have written to SQL script, the query would be as following:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD Depth int; WITH emp AS ( SELECT *, 1 AS d FROM <table_name> WHERE Email =EMAIL UNION ALL SELECT e.*, emp.d + 1 FROM <table_name> e INNER JOIN emp ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber), ForUpd as (SELECT PersonnelNumber, d FROM emp) UPDATE <table_name> SET Depth = B.d FROM <table_name> A JOIN ForUpd B ON A.PersonnelNumber = B.PersonnelNumber
```

- According to the error message, the problem is with `Email = EMAIL`. This is because EMAIL column does not exist. If `EMAIL` is on of the column values for `Email` column, then has to be enclosed in single quotes.
- Instead of using `@concat()` and complicating the process to write a query, you can use string interpolation. Using `@{...}`, you can use dynamic content within a string. Look at the following example.
- I am creating a table using string interpolation in the following demonstration.

```
create table @{variables('table_name')} (id int, name varchar(20))
```

[image]

- So, first use set variable activity to store the table name in a `my_table` variable with the value

```
@concat('tbl',replace(pipeline().RunId,'-',''))
```

- Now replace your dynamic content in script activity with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE @{variables('my_table')} ADD Depth int; WITH emp AS ( SELECT *, 1 AS d FROM @{variables('my_table')} WHERE Email ='EMAIL' UNION ALL SELECT e.*, emp.d + 1 FROM @{variables('my_table')} e INNER JOIN emp ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber), ForUpd as (SELECT PersonnelNumber, d FROM emp) UPDATE @{variables('my_table')} SET Depth = B.d FROM @{variables('my_table')} A JOIN ForUpd B ON A.PersonnelNumber = B.PersonnelNumber
```